# Execute Values You will need to rewrite or cast the expression

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to perform bulk insert into a table with schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (symbol VARCHAR(16), ts timestamp)
```

I have an array of values to insert of the form

```
[('AAPL',1528004700), ('AAPL', 1528005600)]
```

My insert query looks as shown below

```
insert into test VALUES %s
```

and my python code to perform the insert looks like

```
psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cursor, insert_stmt, [('AAPL',1528004700), ('AAPL', 1528005600)])
```

I am getting an error

```
ProgrammingError: column "ts" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type integer
LINE 1: insert into test VALUES ('AAPL',1528004700),('AAPL',15280056...
                                        ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I understand to_timestamp can fix this problem while inserting however execute_values does not let me add multiple placeholders and I need to perform bulk inserts everytime. The timestamp should be free of timezone. how can I fix this error

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

execute_batch() works perfectly as I am able to add to_timestamp in the placeholder section

```
insert = "insert into test VALUES (%s, to_timestamp(%s))"
```

followed by

```
psycopg2.extras.execute_batch(cur, insert, [('AAPL',1528004700), ('AAPL', 1528005600)])
```

However I would like to use execute_values as it is slightly faster than execute_batch()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
from datetime import datetime
psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cursor, insert_stmt, [('AAPL',datetime.fromtimestamp(1528004700)), ('AAPL', datetime.fromtimestamp(1528005600))])
```

Edit:
In general, Postgres has no way of guessing that your 1528004700 is a timestamp, you need to state it explicitly in some way. Your solution with to_timestamp places "this is a timestamp" on the Postgres side, above code places it on the python side. From the information point of view they are equivalent, I did not check which one is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure about `psycopg2.extras.execute_values` but the usual way is to use the method `executemany` to insert a list of records

The insert statement is written with a `%s` for each column. In this particular case, we need also to cast the integer to a timestamp. luckily postgresql provides a to_timestamp function to do just that.

```
values = [('AAPL',1528004700), ('AAPL', 1528005600)]
stmt = 'insert into test values (%s, to_timestamp(%s))'
cur.executemany(stmt, values)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer however executemany is not as effiicient for bulk inserts , the slowest method would be executemany while the fastest method is execute values, execute batch is 1% slower than execute values